# Can the "Network Graph" functionality now deprecated from GitHub be replicated (possibly in git)?

Tags: git, github

The "Network Graph" functionality in GitHub showed branches visually. (Rather than explain it, here's a [blog post](https://github.blog/2008-04-10-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer/) regarding the feature's release.)

This functionality was [deprecated today](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-01-deprecating-the-network-graph/). Some members of my team found this visualization useful. Is there a way to replicate it? Possibly with `git log --graph`? (I know that `git log` only references the current branch, so it seems that more would be required.)

Comment: Network graph is for forks, which isn't a thing in local git (afaik).

Comment: @evolutionxbox Fair enough - is there another good tactic?

Comment: @user3.1415927 When was the network graph disabled?

Comment: @A.H. Today: https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-01-deprecating-the-network-graph/ Added that information to the question.

Comment: I've never found the GitHub network graph to be reliable. It might be a bit useful, but it was often just plain wrong. To get something both reliable and useful, you'd need visibility into all forks (which GitHub have but as individual users, we don't) and a lot of processing power (which we have, but in effect, due to the sheer number of repositories and forks, they—GitHub—do not). I suspect they dropped them because making them reliable got too hard.

Comment: The blog post seems to be gone today, and the Network Graph is back.  Did someone miss April fools day by a month?

Comment: @mw. That could be, but this seems less like a joke than most April fool's-type things